# Trying to get my button to refresh page every time its clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I created a program that randomly pulls two different jobs and genders from a spreadsheet when a single button is pushed. It works initially; however, I don't know how to get the button to clear out the information and randomly select two new genders and jobs.  Right now it adds the same job on the same line when clicked a second time.  I need to close the program, then reopen it to get two new jobs.  Any help? Thanks!

```
import xlrd
import random
from tkinter import *

#Reading the webpage
file_location = "C:/Users/jt/OneDrive/Documents/jobs.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

#Reading the webpage
sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
job = random.randint(0, 1350)
job2 = random.randint(0, 1350)

jobs1 = sheet1.cell_value(job, 0)
jobs2 = sheet1.cell_value(job2, 0)

#Pair the gender with the job randomly
sheet2 = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
gender = random.randint(0, 1)
gender2 = random.randint(0, 1)

genders1 = sheet2.cell_value(gender, 0)
genders2 = sheet2.cell_value(gender2, 0)

def first():
    x = genders1 +" "+ jobs1
    output1.insert(END, x)
    return

def second():
    y = genders2 + " " + jobs2
    output2.insert(END, y)
    return

def callback():
    first()
    second()
    return

window = Tk()
window.title("Writer's Block Killer")
window.configure(background="black")
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="giphy.gif")
Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

#Create label
Label (window, text = "Click \"VS\" to begin:", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
#Create a submit button
Button(window, text="VS", width=5, command=callback) .grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=N)

#Create a text box
output1 = Text(window, width=75, height=1, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output1.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N)

#Second text box
output2 = Text(window, width=75, height=1, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output2.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N)

#run the main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear a entry/text wedged you need to add

```py
# For text wedged
output1.delete(1.0, END)

# For entry wedged
output1.delete(0, END)
```

And you will add it on first() and every time wen you press the button will be deleted

```py
def first():
    x = genders1 +" "+ jobs1
    output1.delete(1.0, END)
    output1.insert(END, x)
    return
```

Or you make a new button what will delete all entrys

```py
def clearAllEntry():
    output1.delete(1.0, END)
    output2.delete(1.0, END)
```

I got your answer but is hard to explain the code in one line so see here:

```py
# This is just an example, I don't have your files to know how to solve it
# But here is how to avoid same value on random selection
import random
# Add this
jobLast = 2

# This will be something like "def first()" so you can update it to this
def Example():
    global jobLast
    print("last >>", jobLast)

    # Make shore is na new value
    job = random.randint(0, 2)
    while job == jobLast:
        job = random.randint(0, 2)
        print("select >>", job)

    # After was found a new value then the last one, update for the next check
    jobLast = job
    print("new >>", jobLast)

    # uppdate "jobs1" whit a new value
    # You can have this line just here, so you can move that line here to avoid repetition
    #jobs1 = sheet1.cell_value(job, 0)

    # New define x value
    genders1 = random.randint(0, 1)
    x = str(genders1) +" "+ str(job)

    print("x >>", x)

Example()
```

Output:

```
last >> 2
select >> 2
select >> 2
select >> 0
new >> 0
x >> 0 0
```

Is normal to "**random**" to give you same value some time because by default they do not save the last selection to give you a new value... But when you make random selection on your original code, every time when you start the software **job** will have different value just on start, so you need to make that random selection in the function to make shore every time that button pressed will give you a different **job** value

Comment: The new button worked.  Thanks! However, when I click on the VS button again, it pulls up the same information as before and not two randomly generated listings from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Look again on the code, I update the last part of how to make shore if the random value will not repeat